# Can not add ReamlList inside RealmObject

Tags: android, realm

I have RealmObject class and also have RealmList inside RealmObject.I try to add some datas in my RealmList,but i can't.
This is my RealObject class

```
public class VinScannerHistoryModel extends RealmObject {
@Required
private String vinNumber;
@Required
private String userName;
@Required
private String status;
private RealmList<ImagesObject> imagesObjects;

@Required
private String key;

public String getVinNumber() {
    return vinNumber;
}

public void setVinNumber(String vinNumber) {
    this.vinNumber = vinNumber;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public RealmList<ImagesObject> getImagesObjects() {
    return imagesObjects;
}

public void setImagesObjects(RealmList<ImagesObject> imagesObjects) {
    this.imagesObjects = imagesObjects;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public String getPolygon() {
    return polygon;
}

public void setPolygon(String polygon) {
    this.polygon = polygon;
}

@Required
private String polygon;
```

}

This is a RealmList class

```
public class ImagesObject extends RealmObject {
public String getImageName() {
    return imageName;
}

public void setImageName(String imageName) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
}

private String imageName;
```

}

I try to add some values like this

```
    private void insertIntoDatabase()
{
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    ImagesObject imagesObject = mRealm.createObject(ImagesObject.class);
    VinScannerHistoryModel vinScannerHistoryModel = mRealm.createObject(VinScannerHistoryModel.class);
    vinScannerHistoryModel.setVinNumber(vinNumber.getText().toString());
    vinScannerHistoryModel.setStatus("Justsaved");
    if(Global.imagePath!=null && Global.imagePath.size()>0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Global.imagePath.size(); i++) {
            imagesObject.setImageName(Global.imagePath.get(i));
        }

        vinScannerHistoryModel.getImagesObjects().add(imagesObject);
    }
    if(checkBox.isChecked())
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setKey("1");
    else
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setKey("0");
    vinScannerHistoryModel.setPolygon(polygonAdapter.getItem(spinnerPosition).getId()+"");
    vinScannerHistoryModel.setUserName(vinScannerModel.getName());
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}
```

[image: When i run my app and debug it i have like this result]
You can see that imageName is null.
I don't know what is a wrong in my code.

Comment: Please read the relevant section of the documentation faq https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I did not understand it.Realm does not support toString method

Comment: Realm supports custom toString method since 0.88.0 what on earth kind of version are you using?